# installing Scilab in OpenSUSE 11.3

Tags: yum, opensuse, software-installation

I want to install Scilab on OpenSUSE 11.3. Which repository is it located in? I cannot find it listed in the package manager. I have tried to install the rpm manually, but I cannot resolve the dependencies.

Comment: What are the dependencies that you cannot resolve? At least post some terminal output so others can guess the problem. Was [this page](http://en.opensuse.org/Scilab) in the openSUSE wiki of any help to you? I also found a link labeled "1-Click install" [here](http://software.opensuse.org/search?q=scilab&baseproject=openSUSE:Factory&exclude_filter=home:&exclude_debug=true). Does it work?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as phunehehe suggested - you can use http://software.opensuse.org/search to search openSUSE BuildService for packages. Select your distribution and it will provide you with one-click install button. To answer your question, scilab can be found in Education repository.